# Field that is never assigned?

Tags: dll, c#

I am reversing a DLL insied a Unity game with .NET Reflector, and I found some weird fields.
They are **never assinged**, there was no item under the **Assigned by** while there were some items under the **Used by**.

How is this explained?

Reflection?
Native side assign?

Comment: Could they be just remnant from previous version of the code?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail to get any meaningful answer. Could be the things you suggest, could be a Reflector bug, could be a library that has features which depend on those fields that your software doesn't use, and probably many more.